# Troubles with cmake and gengetopt

Tags: cmake

I am trying to install a program for astrophysical computations ([https://bitbucket.org/cosmicvoids/vide_public/src/master/](https://stackoverflow.com)) but when I am doing the step 'python3 setup.py build' for Linux, I get the following error. Could anyone give me some advise on how to solve this?

The only thing that came up to my mind was checking the version of cmake, making sure it was new enough.

Comment: "I get the following error" - You seem to forgot attach the **error message** itself. Without it your problem is not clear.